# Refactor mass assigning from a hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Here is the piece of my controller action that takes a `session[:auth]` hash and then assigns the values to the ActiveRecord object represented by `@user` whilst the key names happen to be the same.

```
def new
  @user = User.new

  if session[:auth].present?
    @user.first_name = session[:auth].extra.raw_info.first_name
    @user.last_name = session[:auth].extra.raw_info.last_name
    @user.username = session[:auth].extra.raw_info.username
    @user.email = session[:auth].extra.raw_info.email
  end
end
```

I wonder if there's a way to eliminate the duplications in assigning the values from the hash to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
def new
  attrs = %w(first_name last_name username email).map do |param|
    [param, session[:auth].extra.raw_info.send(param)]
  end
  @user = User.new Hash[attrs]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To add something to Flambino's answer, I'd suggest moving any non-trivial code to the model (code is then easier to test, re-usable and controllers are kept simple):

```
class User
  def self.new_from_auth(auth)
    attributes = [:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email]
    user_attributes = if auth 
      info = auth.extra.raw_info
      Hash[attributes.map { |attr| [attr, info.send(attr)] }]
    else
      {}
    end
    User.new(user_attributes)
  end
end 

class UsersController
  def new
    @user = User.new_from_auth(session[:auth])
  end
end
```